# Django - Granting custom permissions to a user

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin, admin

I have a user profile model with a custom permission defined as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):

    # A few profile fields here...

    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('can_approve', _(u'Can review and approve new accounts')),
        )
```

When I actually look at Profile objects in the Django admin site though, I don't see any way to actually grant this permission to users.

What's the easiest way to do this?  (e.g. give user Joe the 'can_approve' permission?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding a permission to Meta is not enough to see it in the admin panel. Permissions defined in Meta are only used to create a Permission in auth_permission table when you run `manage.py syncdb`.

Try running syncdb, or add the permission manually to database or create the permission from code. After it is added to db it will be visible in admin panel.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, Permission
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

content_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='myapp', model='Profile')
permission = Permission.objects.create(codename='can_approve',
                                   name=_(u'Can review and approve new accounts'),
                                   content_type=content_type)
```